# MongoDB conditional query on nested document array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi I'm trying to write a conditional query on nested document array.
I've read the document for days and couldn't figure out how to make this work.
DB looks like below :

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "team":"team1",
      "players":[
         {
            "name":"Mario",
            "substitutes":[
               "Luigi",
               "Yoshi"
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Wario",
            "substitutes":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "team":"team2",
      "players":[
         {
            "name":"Bowser",
            "substitutes":[
               "Toad",
               "Mario"
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Wario",
            "substitutes":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Due to my lack of English, it's hard to put but what I'm trying to do is
to find teams that includes all queried players.
Each object in players array, some have substitutes.
For each objects in players array, if one of the queried players is not the main player("players.name"), then I want it to look for if one of substitutes("players.substitutes") is.

```
Team.find({players:{$in:[ 'Mario', 'Wario' ]}}) (mongoose query)
```

this will give me an array with 'team1'.

but what I want to get is both teams because 'Mario' is one of the substitutes for 'Bowser'(team2).

I failed to make a query but what I've been trying is not to use $where since the official MongoDB docs says :

> AGGREGATION ALTERNATIVES PREFERRED
>
> Starting in MongoDB 3.6, the $expr operator allows the use of
> aggregation expressions within the query language. And, starting in
> MongoDB 4.4, the $function and $accumulator allows users to define
> custom aggregation expressions in JavaScript if the provided pipeline
> operators cannot fulfill your application’s needs.
>
> Given the available aggregation operators:
>
> The use of $expr with aggregation operators that do not use JavaScript
> (i.e. non-$function and non-$accumulator operators) is faster than
> $where because it does not execute JavaScript and should be preferred
> if possible. However, if you must create custom expressions, $function
> is preferred over `$where`.

BUT if it could be easily written with `$where` operator then it's totally fine.

Any suggestions or ideas that lead to any further would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your query is incorrect. And it is not very obvious what exactly is your filter criteria. So I am giving two suggestions:

1. If you want to filter all documents that have `name` defined in your matching criteria (which returns both documents):

   `db.Team.find({"players.name":{$in:[ 'Mario', 'Wario' ]}}).pretty()`
2. If you want to filter all documents that have any provided player names in the substitutes array (which returns only one, because team1 doesn't have any substitutes are Mario/Wario)

   `db.Team.find({"players.substitutes":{$in:[ 'Mario', 'Wario' ]}}).pretty()`
3. The names being looked at could be present in `name` or `substitute`

   `db.Team.find({ $or: [{"players.substitutes":{$in:[ 'Mario', 'Wario' ]}},  {"players.name":{$in:[ 'Mario', 'Wario' ]}}] }).pretty()`

Comment: That's what I thought he meant as well. But re-reading it I think he wants all theams where both mario and wario exists but if they exist in players.name or in players.subtitutes does not matter. Then his query makes much more sense. Also, it's not as trivial, and I think it can't be done without an aggregate (or I'm missing something obvious).

Comment: I would include the player.name in his own substitutes, at least that way it would be easy to query. (And filter away before sending to frontend if needed) Then you can use Yahya's no 2 solution.

Comment: It's exactly what ippi explained. I want to filter on players' name first and if it doens't exist, a player's substitite can take place.

Comment: I have added the solution #3, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Just found out that this doesn't work for me : ( 
It's gotta validate each players and if a player doesn't match, then it has to look for whether one of the substitutes match.
#3 query shows me the teams even if they only have one matching player in them.
but I think your answer could lead to something. thanks